# Dynamic price product

Tags: plugins

I started a wordpress project for a client which has an e-commerce part. So I decided to try Woocommerce. Nevertheless I'm not yet familiar with this "big" plugin. The client has several specific needs and I'm not able to say if the plugin would cover those needs.

This is an airsoft website. The users will be able to reserve a match. One of client's needs is:

Depending your stuff, the price changes (49$ for non-equiped and 10$ for those who have their stuff).

If Woocommerce can do it, I would like to know how to implement those features ? 
I mean a "product" will be a "match", but then how to customize it like I would like.

Any help would be apreciated,

regards,

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? For me at least it's difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: When the user is on the page product, in my case a "match reservation, one of those options is "equiped" (I mean he has his own weapons etc.) or "no-equiped". Depending the answer the price changes.

Comment: Then as @Milo said below you should look at product variations. If you're looking at scheduling/time-slots then that's not something WooCommerce supports out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are asking for [product variations](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/user-guide/product-variations/).

Comment: Yes I think. I have to test this feature, thank you :)